# How to setToRecipients to a dynamic string?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to do this:

```
 NSString *string = mEmail;// email is dynamic as per specific entry it is also nsstring
[picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:string, nil]];
```

I know setToRecipients needs an NSArray.

I'm getting error on this.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found it ::--->> MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;// &lt;- very important step if you want feedbacks on what the user did with your email sheet
 
 [picker setSubject:@"Your Beep Notifications"];
 NSMutableArray *numbers;
 NSString *string;
 
 numbers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: memail,nil];
 string = [numbers objectAtIndex:0];   // @"Three"
 
 NSLog(string);
 
 //NSString *temp = ;
 
 
 [picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:string,nil]];

Comment: "cn any one tell me wat m i doing rong". Yes, you are using a keyboard that seems to be broken. Let us know what error you are receiving and we might be able to help. Is it a compiler error or a runtime exception and at which line is it occuring?

Comment: @thnx robin but i hope u did see i found it ... thnx for d help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the error? In the first line, it should be `NSString` instead of nsstring.